# how to use sails.js and socket.io for online game server-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js, multiplayer

I'm trying to create an online multiplayer game. After some digging, I came up with sails and socketio.

The server needs to be real-time. I want to use the sails as my data controller(like player authentication), and the socketio for real-time connection.

Questions:

 1. Is sails able to integrate with socketio?

 2. If so, Can I connect to socket.io with a connection from my game? (NO Javascipts in client side), and how?

 3. Is there something I'm missing? any other options?

EDIT:
 1. how can I use sails as my authentication system for online players and socket.io as my real-time connection?

5. The connection must be TCP or UDP or I should use HTTP?


Does anyone have any experience in online gaming? please give me hint where to start and what to use for a multiplayer online game like MOBA games?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Sails works great with Socket.io and there are plenty of tuts on it. Here is some documentation to get you started. https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/0.9/sockets.md
2. You could, but that will depend on how you communicate with the server. The docs should steer you to your solution. Sorry I can't elaborate on this as I'm not a game dev, but I do use Socket.io in application development.
3. Maybe you could check out something like Firebase as well?

Comment: Thanks @4Dev. what do you think of django with gevent-socketio?